# PHP - Detecting image filesize before saving image

Tags: php, file-get-contents, file-put-contents

I am using the following code to save an image from a URL but sometimes the image URL is bad and there is no image there, OR there is an issue with the image and it saves a zero size file.

```
<?php 
file_put_contents ("/var/www/html/images/" . $character . ".jpg", 
    file_get_contents($image));
```

I need to try and find a way to stop this happening as this creates a problem (saving zero size files).

I have tried this, but it still seems to be happening:

```
$filesize = file_put_contents ("/var/www/html/images/" . $character . ".jpg", 
    file_get_contents($image));

if (($filesize < 10) || ($filesize == "")) {
    echo "Error";
}
```

Could anyone recommend a more reliable way to do this?

Comment: Is totally unclear what you are asking. Please, edit your question in order to clarify it.

Comment: I am asking if there is a better way to detect if the image I am saving has a filesize of zero bytes.

Comment: Why do you do not google for: "filesize php"? The first result link to official PHP doc filesize() function

Comment: @felipsmartins Thank you for your unhelpful comments, I know how to Google and clearly others understood my question. I know how to get the filesize in PHP, I was asking if I could get it before I saved it. Have a nice day.

Comment: `$foo = file_get_contents(); if(strlen($foo)) { file_put_contents('somefile', $foo);` …?

Answer (score 3):

Imagick package has methods for doing this

[Imagick::getImageGeometry()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagegeometry.php) - returns width and height of an image, or throws an exception.

```
function isValidImage($filename)
{
    if (!fileexists($filename) return false;
    if (filesize($filename) == 0) return false;

    $image = new imagick($filename);
    $img=$image->getImageGeometry();

    return ($img['width'] > 0 && $img['height'] > 0);
}
```

EDIT: I have updated my answer with more checks

Comment: sorry, but what does it have to do with the question?

Comment: "Issue with an image" is a bit vague. I have updated my answer with more checks

Comment: This solution will require [ImageMagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) to be installed which does not usually happen in a default PHP installation.

Comment: Yes! Reliably checking if a file contains image data requires parsing the file.

Comment: That is not proper way in order to validate/detect whether file is image or not. It feels wrong and it's not idiomatic. It would recommend to use *fileinfo* instead

Comment: Look at this post here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php#75275 "Tempting as it may seem to use finfo_file() to validate uploaded image files (Check whether a supposed imagefile really contains an image), the results cannot be trusted."

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to get an image size by URL. I have `get_headers()` function to get the image size. Here is an example which is given below:

```
function checkImageSize($imageUrl){
   if(!empty($imageUrl)){
       $file_headers = @get_headers($imageUrl, 1); // it gives all header values .
       // for image size, we use **Content-Length** for size.
       $sizeInKB = round($file_headers['Content-Length'] / 1024, 2));           
       return $sizeInKB;
   } else {
       return 0;
   }
}
$imageSize =checkImageSize($imageUrl);
if($imageSize<=$conditionalSize){
     // upload code
} else {
     // error msg
}
```